# Realm - List vs Result. Speed and size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I need to pass near about 1000-1500 objects from one controller to another. My concern is basically on the speed. Will it affect if i send list or result. Or should i pass predicate and query it again. Then access the list of the queried object.

To be more clear.
I have object named Chat, which has a list of media. Now i wanna pass that media. What would be the best practice for that.
Also sometimes i need to filter the media. I then convert that result to list by using reduce func.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Realm `Results` objects, then you don't need to worry about this. Objects stored in `Results` are only lazily loaded into memory when your code specifically requests them. As such, passing the `Results` object around won't incur any overhead.

That being said, if you then use the native Swift `reduce` function to create a filtered array from a `Results` object, that would become a problem. That operation will go through and force each item in `Results` to get lazily-loaded at once, which could lead to memory issues. If possible, you should instead try and perform that operation using the Realm `filter()` method to produce another `Results` object.